# Display a form with multiple ng-repeat after all content has been loaded

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a form with multiple ng-repeat block and other blocks without ng-repeat. How do I wait until the all content has been loaded before rendering the form

As an example

```
<form name="forms.confirmForm" ng-submit="submitForm()">

    <div>
      <div ng-repeat="phone in candidate.phones" style="position:relative">
       -- write out some value 
    </div>

    <div class="small-12">
      <label>first name
      </label>
      <input name="firstName" type="text"  />

      <div ng-repeat="phone in candidate.email" style="position:relative">
           -- write out some value 
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="apply-bar">
        <button class="button button-apply" type="submit">
          apply
        </button>
    </div>
</form>
```

** The information comes from a model and it is loaded once . The ng-repeat is just taking parts of the model and iterating

Comment: how is everything loaded? Do you have multiple `$http` requests? If yes, then you can collect their Promises and run through `$q.all()` to synchronise. Simply set some kind of flag in `.then` on success callback and use `ng-if="flag"` on the form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways you can handle this.

1. You initialise your model (candiate) with an empty array of phones/email. In which case you don't need to do anything in the template as the ng-repeat will apply `0` times. Resulting in nothing being rendered.
2. You use ng-if to prevent rendering when you don't have your model(candidate) and/or ng-if to prevent your ng-repeat trying to render when your model doesn't have phone/emails.

Try this based on the second option;

```
<form name="forms.confirmForm" ng-submit="submitForm()">

    <div ng-if="candidate"> <!--Prevent rendering if there is no candiate model-->
        <div
            ng-if="candidate.phones" <!--Prevent rendering if canidate doesn't have phones param-->
            ng-repeat="phone in candidate.phones"
            style="position:relative"
        >
            -- write out some value
        </div>

        <div class="small-12">
            <label>first name
            </label>
            <input name="firstName" type="text"/>

            <div
                ng-if="candidate.email"
                ng-repeat="phone in candidate.email"
                style="position:relative"
            >
                -- write out some value
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="apply-bar">
            <button class="button button-apply" type="submit">
                apply
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Your first approach will make <form> visible including submit button. ng-if i think what OP is looking.

Comment: form tags don't have a visible property and the submit button is wrapped in the same div as the ng-if="candidate" so it won't be visible.

Answer (score 1):

use `ng-if` to check whether array items have been loaded.

```
<form name="forms.confirmForm" ng-submit="submitForm()"
      ng-if="candidate.phones.length > 0 && candidate.email.length > 0">
```

Comment: Thanks but sometimes I may not have any phone# or email#.

Comment: This solution means both phones and emails must exist before either can be rendered. You also don't need to check if the length is great than 0, you can check just length as a boolean. 0 would equal to false and 1 or more would equal to true.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ng-if in your div :

```
<div ng-if="candidate.phones">
  <div ng-repeat="phone in candidate.phones" style="position:relative">
   -- write out some value 
  </div>`
```